# What could be the reason for display mode specific view lookup to fail after a while?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a ASP.NET MVC 4 (4.0.40804.0) web app running on 6 Windows Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5.

On app startup we clear the existing display modes and replace them like this:

```
var modes = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes;
var mobile = new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
{
   ContextCondition = c => c.IsMobile()
};

var tablet = new DefaultDisplayMode("Tablet")
{
   ContextCondition = c => c.IsTablet()
};
var desktop = new DefaultDisplayMode();

modes.Clear();
modes.Add(mobile);
modes.Add(tablet);
modes.Add(desktop);
```

where `IsMobile` and `IsTablet` are extension methods that basically match the User-Agent header value against a regular expression. This works as expected until after a while server by server starts to pick the default views instead of the mobile views for requests with a matching User-Agent header. I know the extension method is not at fault since it is used in another place to determine the value of an attribute and that continues to work just fine. Somehow the current display mode is no longer accounted for during the lookup of the views.

The application is based on a proprietary MVC 4 app that brings its own view engine (based on `RazorViewEngine`), so my first guess is that the bug lies there but I was wondering if anyone else has observed the same phenomenon in a vanilla ASP.NET MVC application or has any insights on how to best find the root cause.